# Accessing a map from a different jenkins file and getting key

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a constants.groovy like below

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
def emailDistributionList = ['catalogSuccess':'ccc@ff.com, fff.ddd@gmail.com', 'catalogFailure':'fffee@ofr.com']

return this;
```

Now I have a Jenkins pipeline main script as below

```
node ('node1') {
    stage("Read Constants") {
        script {
           def constants = evaluate readTrusted('jenkins_pipeline/constants.groovy')
           def catalogDistributionList = "${constants.emailDistributionList}"
           echo "${catalogDistributionList}"
           def successList = "${catalogDistributionList.catalogSuccess}"
           echo "${successList}"
        }
    }
}
```

Now first `echo` prints the `Field` from constants file sucessfully. But when I try read a key from that and print it using the second `echo` it throws error

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: catalogSuccess for class: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
```

I think it's reading the `Field` from `constants.groovy` as a `String` and not a `Map`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

We cannot read the `map` to a variable and then get the `key`. Instead everything has to be done in one shot.

It has to be done this way

`def catalogDistributionList = "${constants.emailDistributionList.catalogSuccess}"`